# Can TiDB Syncer run normally when the MySQL table character set is latin1?

Tags: tidb

I see PingCAP FAQ said that
"The character sets of TiDB use UTF-8 by default and currently only support UTF-8"

If MySQL table character set is latin1, can Syncer run correctly or can I get the same result in the TiDB side as in the MySQL side?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, TiDB uses utf8mb4 as the default character set. If the upstream MySQL character set is latin1, the Syncer can run normally and the results are consistent.